# Rails model association problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, associations

I'm new at active record association in rails so i don't know how to solve the following problem:

I have a tables called 'meetings' and 'users'. I have correctly associated these two together by making a table 'participants' and set the following association statements:

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :participants, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :users, :through => :participants
```

and

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :meeting
    belongs_to :user
```

and the last model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :participants, :dependent => :destroy
```

At this point all is going well and i can access the user values of attending participants of a specific meeting by calling @meeting.users in the normal meeting>show.html.erb view.

Now i want to make connections between these participants. Therefore i made a model called 'connections' and created the columns of 'meeting_id', 'user_id' and 'connected_user_id'. So these connections are kinda like friendships within a certain meeting.

My question is: How can i set the model associations so i can easily control these connections?

I would like to see a solution where i could use

```
@meeting.users.each do |user|
    user.connections.each do |c|
        <do something>
    end
end
```

I tried this by changing the model of meetings to this:

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :participants, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :users, :through => :participants
    has_many :connections, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :participating_user_connections, :through => :connections, :source => :user
```

Please, does anyone have a solution/tip how to solve this the rails way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a wrong understanding on how the associations in Models work. Because of this wrong view my question was wrong to begin with.

For example I have a model meetings Meetings which has many Participants from the model Participants. I didn't knew that I cannot only retrieve the meeting.participants, but that i can also access the meeting that the participant is assigned to with participant.meeting.

So i just simply changed the columns user_id and connected_user_id of table participant to participant_id and connected_participant_id. Then in the models i did.

Model Participant:

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :meeting
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :participating_user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key =>'user_id'
    has_many :connections
```

Model Connection:

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :participant, :foreign_key => 'connected_participant_id'
```

With these associations i could simply access the connections of the corresponding participant in the view by using:

View (haml code)

```
- @meeting.participants.each do |p|
    %p
        %b Participant:
        = "#{p.user.first_name} #{p.user.last_name}"
    - p.connections.each do |c|
        %p
        %b Participant:
        = "#{c.participant.user.first_name} #{c.participant.user.last_name}"
```

One last thing, these nested resources of c.participant.user.firstname is very long. I rather like to see something like p.connected_participants that would address the Participant model. 
Does anyone know how to shorten these nested resources?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your problem is that you want to make a connection between users who attended the same meeting.Maybe this will work.

In the Participant model

```
 has_many => :connections
 has_many => :users, :through => :connections
```

In the User model

```
has_many => :connections
```

Then I suppose you can do :

```
@meeting.users.each do |user|
    user.connections.each do |c|
        #access each user object through the object |c|
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, however i had a wrong understanding of the model associations. Therefore my question was wrong to begin with. See my own solution how i solved the problem.